# remote access to mysql on Ec2

Tags: php, mysql, database, amazon-ec2

I have two amazon ec2 instances. One I am using as a webserver and the other one has the mysql DB. I have the below php script that I run from the web Server. I cant seem to connect to my Database. When I run the php script on the mysql server with $host= localhost, it works. How can I access the mysql server?

```
<?php


$host="ipaddress";              // Host name
$username="root";    // Mysql username
$password="mypassword";           // Mysql password
$db_name="myDB";             // Database name
$port=3306;



// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name,$port);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else
 {

       echo "Connected";
 }


?>
```

Comment: At a guess you don't have a security group on the MySQL machine that allows the webserver machine to access it.  Do you have a security group that allows port 3306 from your server machine?  Be careful to not open that port to the world (0.0.0.0).

Comment: Also, RedHat and IIRC, Windows EC2 instances enable firewall on the machine itself (iptables on RedHat). So, you may need to configure or disable that as well. Amazon image does *not* enable iptables

Answer (score 2):

1. Have the user/host combo as a legitimate user in mysql.user

   select user,host from mysql.user;
2. Have the aws ec2 security group open (the aws Firewall)

There are three choices here: my IP, custom, or anywhere for the ip addr CIDR

3. Have the mysql server configured to allow remote connections.

This is the bind-address and skip-networking setup. See the [nixcraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) document for those few changes if needed.

Comment: @Drew- I am able to  connect to the mysql Db using a Gui tool "HeidiSQL" using the pubic ip. But when I try it using my php code it does not work/

Comment: I am at drewpierce747 gmail

Comment: @Drew- my code works correctly when I run it on http://phpfiddle.org/. But when I run it on my server it doesn't  work.